# `wp_editor()` CSS messing up the jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, wp-editor

I have a custom admin page that includes both the user of `wp_editor()` and a jQuery dialog.

For reasons unknown to me, the instance of `wp_editor()` uses some of the same css class names as dialog, and one in particular (`ui-widget-overlay`) is messing up my jQuery dialog. I'm unable to interact with the dialog due to the `z-index` of the overlay as set by `editor.css`, and the overlay is darker, with a stripe in the middle.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? If so, how did you work around it?

```
function do_refreshing_invitees_dialog(){
?>  
    <script>
    $(function(){

        /**
         * The 'refresh invitees' dialog
         */
        $('#refresh-invitees-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            open: function(event, ui){ 
                /** Hide the 'x' close button */
                $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
            },
        });

    });
    </script>
    <div id="refresh-invitees-dialog" title="Refreshing Event Invitess">
        <div id="dialog-spinner" style="float: left; margin: 17px 10px 0 0;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->loader_path; ?>ajax-loader-bulk-dialog-invitees.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="dialog-message">
            <p>Please wait while the refreshed invitee's are generated...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

[image: Dialog working fine, but CSS messed up by wp_editor()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a fun one had to make some mods to make this one work....
add this to your theme stylesheet (style.css):

```
    .ui-front {
        z-index: 1001 !important;
    }
    .ui-widget-overlay {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000 !important;
        opacity: .6 !important;
        filter: Alpha(Opacity = 60) !important;
    }
```

This should override the editor.css. Let me know if this does not work...
Tom

Comment: Thanks @tnory56. I did pretty much this a couple of days back, and it did work. The only trouble of course is that it overrides the `wp_editor()` css. What WP needs is a way of uniquely identifying the editor for applying it's css. I've also looked down the jQuery scoping root for my dialog, but because the WP style sheet that styles the editor specifically targets `.ui-widget-overlay`, it still overwrites it.